# Efficiently find closest pairs in two vectors?

Tags: c++, algorithm, binary-search

Given two sorted vectors of type double, where the vectors may be of different sizes, I'd like to generate a list of pairs, one element from each of the two vectors, where the difference between the elements in a pair is minimized, and no two pairs share an element. The vectors are both rather large, and the task must be accomplished in a very short amount of time.

I've tried using a binary search (see below), terminating in a comparison of neighboring elements to determine the "closest" match, however it is not efficient enough to complete the task in the required time frame.

Interpolation search takes just as long. Using `std::lower_bound()` in some algorithm vastly speeds up the code, however it doesn't consider elements *less than* the search value.

Is there a nice way to do this?

```
double binarySearch(vector<double> vec, double val) {
       int left = 0; 
       int right = vec.size();
    
       while (left <= right) {
              int mid = (left+right)/2;

              if (vec[mid] == val)
                  return mid;
              else if (vec[mid] < val)
                       left = mid + 1;
              else 
                       right = mid - 1;
       }

       return minimum(vec[mid], vec[mid+1], vec[mid-1]);
}
```

Comment: Your question has some ambiguity. Are the two vectors of unequal sizes? In particular is A much longer than B? Since you say you don't want pairs to share elements, what is your objective function for the problem as a whole?

Comment: *Using std::lower_bound() in some algorithm vastly speeds up the code* -- All `lower_bound` does is do what your code is attempting to do.  Thus your hand-made binary search is flawed in some way.  Also, post a [mcve].  Maybe the issue is that your hand-made binary search has bugs you are not aware of.

Comment: See above for my binary search implementation.

Comment: Both vectors must be sorted, and then a simple algorithm starts iterating simultaneously through both vectors, from the beginning of the end, comparing the difference between the two values being iterated over, peeking at the next value in each vector and figuring out if it would produce a smaller difference. A slightly tricky algorithm, due to all the edge cases.

Comment: Not clear what you mean by a 'pair'. Does it mean two values at the same index in each of the two given vectors? Or two values at arbitrary positions? Or may be two values from the same vector are acceptable, too? (For example, in vectors {1,2} and {200,210} the closest pair might be 1 and 2.)

Comment: Can you give a few examples of two input vectors and the resulting `std::vector<std::pair<double, double>>` that you want?

Comment: Descriptions says `Given two sorted vectors of type double` code sample has one vector as argument. Also `difference between the elements in a pair is minimized` is not well defined, some mathematical formula is needed. Also how many pairs must be generated? All elemets from smaller array must be used?

Comment: What does it mean _'no two pairs share an element'_...? If one vector is {0, 0, 0} and the other one is {1, 1, 1} is a single pair (0,1) an answer, or is it a triple of such pairs?

Comment: What requirement from this problem prohibits you from returning an empty list?

Comment: If you mean that given two numerically sorted vectors u and v of equal size, you are trying to solve for argmin_i(abs(u[i]-v[i])), then I believe (I'm probably wrong) that O(n) is the best you can do. The index does not give you much useful information about the distance, despite the fact that they are sorted. You'd have to iterate over every pair, compute their distance, and keep track of the smallest distance observed. If you mean that u and v are not necessarily equal size, and you are trying to find argmin_i,j(abs(u[i] - v[j])), that is perhaps a more interesting problem

Answer (score 1):

Hope this is what do you mean:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <cstddef>
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>
#include <utility>
#include <vector>

template<class T>
std::vector<std::pair<T, T>> getClosestPairs(std::vector<T> v1, std::vector<T> v2) {
    std::vector<std::pair<T, T>> vPair;
    std::pair<size_t, size_t> indexs;
    std::pair<T, T> close;

    size_t i = 0, j = 0;
    T minDiff = std::numeric_limits<T>::max();

    while(v1.size() != 0 && v2.size() != 0) {
        while(i < v1.size() && j < v2.size()) {
            T diff = v1[i] < v2[j] ? v2[j] - v1[i] : v1[i] - v2[j];
            if(diff < minDiff) {
                minDiff = diff;
                // save index to delete them
                indexs = {i, j};
                // save the closest pair
                close = {v1[i], v2[j]};
            } else { // reached to min no need to move on res the cells
                break;
            }

            // Move the smaller vector's index forward
            if(v1[i] < v2[j]) {
                i++;
            } else {
                j++;
            }
        }
        vPair.push_back(close);
        v1.erase(v1.begin() + indexs.first);
        v2.erase(v2.begin() + indexs.second);
        i = j = 0;
        minDiff = std::numeric_limits<T>::max();
    }
    return vPair;
}
int main() {
    std::vector<double> v1 = {1, 4, 5, 7, 8, 13, 49};
    std::vector<double> v2 = {7, 10, 11, 15, 40};
    std::vector<std::pair<double, double>> result = getClosestPairs(v1, v2);
    for(auto [a, b] : result) std::cout << a << ',' << b << '\n';
}
```

Output:

```
7,7
8,10
13,11
5,15
49,40
```

Answer (score 0):

The best algorithm seems to me as:

1. iterate using two indexers (incrementing the indexer that points to the lower number)
2. if the incremented indexer change => you are at local minimum
   Check if its lower than the best result and either:

2.1 already have a better minimum -> disregard it
2.2 another occurrence of the best delta -> record it
2.3 better then our best delta -> clear results and record new minimum

Comment: Ah, yes, I suppose it does. This is actually for a personal project, however.